# SPIM print ascii char

Tags: assembly, ascii, mips, spim, qtspim

I have to write a little program in assembly for the MIPS architecture. To be more specific it should be a procedure which takes a register and prints the value of it. It is allowed to use everything excepted a call of print_int. My procedure does: 
1. Split up the given register into digits
2. Convert them into ascii
3. Store them on the stack
I now have values like 52 or 53 on the stack and I want to print them with print_string but how can I achieve this? 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Once you have the text representation on the stack, make sure you have a terminating zero byte then just pass the start address to `print_string`.

Comment: [7fffeaec]    0000000049,                                    
[7fffeaf0]    0000000050  0000000051  0000000052  0000000000 i have this values on my stack. But it only prints the 1 what is worng?

Comment: You've pushed each digit as a _word_. They need to be _bytes_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write **3. Store them on the stack**. Since you are **allowed to use everything excepted a call of print_int** why don't you store them in succesive memory bytes before using **print_string** to ouput the result.